# Change color of react base search component

Tags: react-native, components, native, native-base

I have a react base search component and I would like to change the blue color to a other color as in the picture.

[image]

The react code I use to generate comes from the react base website.

```
            <Item>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input
                placeholder="Search"
                defaultValue={this.state.searchvalue}
                onChangeText={searchvalue =>
                  this.setState({ searchvalue: searchvalue })}
              />
              <Icon
                name="ios-close"
                onPress={() => this.empty()}
              />
            </Item>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => this.search()}>
              <Icon
                style={styles.btnLinkIcon}
                name="ios-checkmark-outline"
              />
            </Button>
          </Header>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the background color of Item component <Item>?

Comment: just add the style prop to header and set the backgroundColor to your desired color. `<Header style={{backgroundColor:'#123456'}} searchBar rounded>`

Answer (score 1):

you can do by changing `Header` component `backgroudColor`

```
<Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#000'}} >
       <Item>
          <Icon name="ios-search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search"
            defaultValue={this.state.searchvalue}
            onChangeText={searchvalue =>
              this.setState({ searchvalue: searchvalue })}
          />
          <Icon
            name="ios-close"
            onPress={() => this.empty()}
          />
        </Item>
        <Button transparent onPress={() => this.search()}>
          <Icon
            style={styles.btnLinkIcon}
            name="ios-checkmark-outline"
          />
        </Button>
      </Header>
```